Woocommerce rest API variations attributes
I'm trying to send a new variation to a Woocommerce product. It is correctly created except for the attribute.
I'm sending:
$data = [
    'sku'=> $confezione['CODART'],
    'price'         => $confezione['PREZZO1'],
    'regular_price' => $confezione['PREZZO1'],
    'attributes'    => [
        [
           'id'        =>  3,
           'name'      =>  'confezionamento',
           'slug'      =>  'pa_confezionamento',
           'options'   =>  $tipo
         ]
  ]
];

and the [attributes] is empty
If I compile the variation manually the following attribute is created:
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => confezionamento
                    [slug] => pa_confezionamento
                    [option] => FL 12 x 1 lt
                )

        )

the attributes in product are:
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => confezionamento
                    [slug] => pa_confezionamento
                    [position] => 0
                    [visible] => 1
                    [variation] => 1
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => FL 12 x 1 lt
                            [1] => FL 12 x 750 ml
                            [2] => TA 10 lt
                            [3] => TA 20 lt
                            [4] => TA 4 x 5 lt
                        )

                )

        )

Where is my mistake?
